# Summing of reciporals

Tags: calculus, number-theory

I have found that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^n}=\frac{1}{3}$$.

I have also found that 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{4n-1}}+\frac{1}{2^{4n}}=\frac{1}{5}$$.

Since I am using a phone, I will provide proof in the near future, but is there a way to put $\frac{1}{5}$ in a form like $\frac{1}{3}$ where there is only one term in sigma notation, but infinite terms as a series?

Edit: I mean a single term which is in the form of a reciporal of a number in the form $a^n $

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{1}{5}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{6^n}$?

Comment: @Augustine, is there any proof?

Comment: So.... you aren't familiar with geometric series??? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series

Comment: For style and clarity you should right $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{2^{4n-1}}+\frac{1}{2^{4n}})=\frac{1}{5}$.  I thought you were claiming $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{4n-1}}=\frac{1}{5}-+\frac{1}{2^{4n}}$ which not only isn't true, isn't meaningful.

Comment: @fleablood ??? I don't know what you mean

Comment: When someone says $\sum a + b $ it usually means $(\sum a) + b$ and not $\sum (a + b)$.  Which is obviously what you meant.

Comment: Your $\frac 1{2^{4n-1}} + \frac 1{2^{4n}}$ can be written as $\frac 2{2^{4n}} + \frac 1{2^{4n}} = \frac 3{2^{4n}}$ so you *can* write this in one term as $1/5 = \sum \frac 3{2^{4n}}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that geometric series converges as

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^n}=x\cdot \frac{1}{1-x}, \ \  \text{if} \ \left| \frac1x\right|<1$$

And $$\frac{1}{2^{4n-1}}=\frac{2}{16^n}$$

Thus

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{4n-1}}=2\cdot \frac1{16}\cdot \frac1{1-\frac1{16}}=2\cdot \frac1{16}\cdot \frac1{\frac{15}{16}}=\frac{2}{15}$$

and

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{4n}}= \frac1{16}\cdot \frac1{1-\frac1{16}}= \frac1{16}\cdot \frac1{\frac{15}{16}}=\frac{1}{15}$$

Consequently

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{4n-1}}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{4n}}=\frac{2}{15}+\frac{1}{15}=\frac{3}{15}=\frac15$$

Comment: Out of curiosity why does your latex notation \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$ render the index above and below the sigma where as my latex notation *which is EXACTLY the same* \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$ renders the index to the right?

Comment: The secret are the double latex brackets $\text{\$\$} ... \text{\$\$}$. That´s why I often use them when I have to post a sum.

Comment: double latex brackets????

Comment: Yes. Look again at my comment.

Comment: The first time the \$\$ didn't show up.

Comment: It looks like that it is working.

Comment: It is now.  Thanks.  For a moment I think it didn't escape the dollar signs so instead of \$\$...\$\$ I saw $$...$$ instead and ... I didn't know what to make of it.

Comment: `\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}` if you don't want the double dollar signs, giving $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}$ inline.

Comment: Double dollar signs also center and resize  Those seem nice and easy.  Type it and forget it.  But I'll keep the $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}$ in mind, if I can remember them What does $\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}$ without sum do (or with somethig where limits are in appropriate like $\frac\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}{a}{b}$... I guess, I find out...

Answer (score 0):

For $|r| < 1$ then $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r^n = 1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}r^n = \frac 1{1-r}$  so for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac 1{4^n} = \frac 1{1- \frac 14}-1 = \frac 13$.

$\frac 15 = \frac 65 - 1$ and $\frac 65 = \frac 1{\frac 56} = \frac 1{1- \frac 16}$

So $\frac 15 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac 1{6^n}$.

====

If $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r^n$ converges (a big if) and $r \ne 1$ (a not very big if) then

$(1-r)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r^n = $

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r^n - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r^{n+1} = $

$\sum_n=0^{\infty} r^n - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}r^n =$

$r^0 - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(r^n - r^n) = 1$.

So $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r^n = \frac 1{1-r}$$.

But that does require $\sum r^n$ to converge.  Which happens if $|r| < 1$.

====

Anyway.  You stumbled upon

$\frac 15 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac 1{2^{4n-1}} + \frac 1{2^{4n}})$

Why didn't you simply simplify that?

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac 1{2^{4n-1}} + \frac 1{2^{4n}})=$

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac 2{2^{4n}} + \frac 1{2^{4n}})$

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac 3{2^{4n}}$?

By the way

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac 3{2^{4n}}=$

$3 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac 1{2^{4n}}=$

$3 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac 1{16^n}=$

$3* \frac 1{16-1} = \frac 1{15}$

As you can see $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac 1{k^n} = \frac 1{k-1}$.

Comment: I think it _diverges_. Also, could you answer my question above? It needs to be expressed as a single term.

Comment: What???  I *did* answer your question!  $\frac 15 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac 1{6^n}$ is a single term.  And $|1/6| < 1$ so it converges.  What the heck are you talking about?

Comment: Oh sorry page scrolled down bad phone =(

Comment: As you can tell, I am not that good at maths. Furthermore, I am just a stupid 12 yr old. There is no need to talk to me that way... I feel very offended.